# count of unique values in a column, with speed as a consideration

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a faster way to count unique values in a column?
My second iteration of the formula uses a range for speed but receives a #NAME? error. Thanks.

I have used the following formula to count the number of unique ip addresses in column 5.  --explained by Jeeped on msdn--

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=sumproduct((ipsheet!C[5]<>"""")/ipsheet(ACAS!C[5],ipsheet!C[5]&""""))"
```

the forumula works BUT it is really slow going over 5000+ entries. I have tried implementing the same formula as

```
With Sheets("ipsheet")                                                    'create range for ip addresses
     Set rngOfFindings = .Range(.Range("e1"), .Range("e1").End(xlDown))
End With
"=sumproduct((rngOfFindings<>"""")/countif(rngOfFindings,rngOfFindings&""""))"
```

the result is #NAME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the data in your column as a named range.

Save your file.

Go to Data>From Other Sources>From Microsoft Query

Select Excel Files, then navigate to your Excel file. Open it, select your range, and continue and edit in Microsoft Query.

Click the SQL button, and type

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT rangename.columnheader) FROM rangename rangename
```

Answer (score 0):

For large ranges this formula is longer but faster

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(range<>"",MATCH(range,range,0)),ROW(range)-MIN(ROW(range))),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Dim Lst As Long
Dim Rng As Range

' the last cell in col a that has a value
Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Select

'save the rowNo
Lst = ActiveCell.Row

'Define the range
Set Rng = Range("a1:a" & Lst)

'Go to cell that should contain the sum
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet11").Select                    'select this worksheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet11").Cells(2, 2).Select        'select column to the right of a1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet11").Cells(-1, 0).Select     'check reference related to 2,2

Comment: Problem: count unique ip address in column A.
I have ip addresses in column A labeled IP addresses. Row 2 thru 91 have 7 different ip addresses. I have tried a few different formulas. Most of the the time I get an error #name?. I would like to understand how to deal with this. Yes, the answer would be cool; but i would like to get the understanding of the RC,RC format so that in the future i can programmatically deal with the problem. Currently the last line with the reference .cells(-1,0).select returns application or range error 1004. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't this is correct; but i'll go with for now. sorry